# `date_sub` not working in SQL via laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel-4

I'm having an issue with the following laravel code not returning any rows when executed in Laravel:

```
$entries = DB::table('chemlog')
        ->where('timestamp', '>=','DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY')
        ->orderBy('timestamp','desc')
        ->get();
```

When I execute the following on the MySQL console, it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM chemlog WHERE timestamp >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

What is the difference between what Laravel is assembling and what I wrote on the console?

I'm using:

`PHP 5.5`,
`MySQL 5.6`,
`Laravel 4`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use raw statement:

```
->where('timestamp', '>=', DB::raw('DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)'))
```

The difference is that this is a parametrized query, so it's basically treating it as a string

Comment: can you help a bit getting this error General error: 1 near "1": syntax error (SQL: select * from "users" where "timestamp" < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))

Comment: I have same issue and i am doing this `->whereRaw('\`test_users\`.\`created_at\` <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND \`test_users\`.\`created_at\` >  DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)' )`

Answer (score 0):

**LARAVEL DOES SUPPORT DATE_SUB AND DATE QUERY**

A simple query like, just make sure the database you are using:

*MYSQL:*

```
OfficesHours::limit(10)->get(new Expression("DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 2 DAY) as lastday"));

DB::table("office_hours")->get([new Expression("DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL 2 DAY)")]);
```

*SQLITE:*

```
OfficesHours::limit(10)->get(new Expression("DATE(date, -2 DAY) as lastday"));

DB::table("office_hours")->get([new Expression("DATE(date, -2 DAY)")]);
```